# Bootstrap 4 move to new row if mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to be able to have my router outlet move to the next row if size is mobile.
Currently the profile card just gets removed when it is mobile size.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <!-- TODO if mobile then move to new row -->
  <div class="flex-row-auto offcanvas-mobile w-300px w-xl-350px">
    <profile-card></profile-card>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-row-fluid ml-lg-8">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have another row (that always contains the data, just isn't shown all the time) that only displays on mobile, like:

```
<div class="d-block d-md-none">
<!-- Would have the div visible on XS and SM breakpoints -->
```